# Mysql - Multiple groups query

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I need a little help here
It is very simple problem but I don't know why I can't get what I want

Database

```
store
id | value
5  |   s

favorite
id | store_id | value
1  |    5     |   f
2  |    5     |   f 
3  |    5     |   f

party
id  |store_id | value
1   |    5    |  p
2   |    5    |  p
```

my query :

```
SELECT COUNT(p.`id`) AS parties, COUNT(f.`id`) AS favorites,s.* FROM store s
LEFT JOIN party p ON p.`store_id` = s.`id`
LEFT JOIN favorite f ON f.`store_id` = s.`id`
GROUP BY s.`id`
```

result

```
parties | favorites |   id   | value
   6    |     6     |    5   |   s
```

this is the result I want

```
parties | favorites |   id   | value
   2    |     3     |    5   |   s
```

Can anyone help me?, I already tried all approach I can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count `DISTINCT` id's if you want a separate count of parties/favorites per store, that will eliminate the duplicates you're getting due to the `JOIN`;

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.`id`) AS parties, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT f.`id`) AS favorites,
       s.* 
FROM store s 
LEFT JOIN party p ON p.`store_id` = s.`id` 
LEFT JOIN favorite f ON f.`store_id` = s.`id` 
GROUP BY s.`id`;
```

Comment: Thanks, it really answer my question